# Mongoose dup key when using node-uuid

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Why would I run into "dup key" errors when setting the _id of a Mongoose schema to a function?..

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid');

var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1() },
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});

var test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

module.exports = test;
```

And, I was attempting to new up a new Test model each time...

```
var testA = new Test({
    name: 'test A'
});
testA.save(function(err, testA){
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failure saving test A: ' + err);
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
});

var testB = new Test({
    name: 'test B'
});
testB.save(function(err, testB){
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failure saving test B: ' + err);
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

When trying to seed my database I ran into duplicate _id values on any collection any time I attempted to create multiple documents.  Even nesting the individual document saves in the callback of the previous failed.

I assumed the function would have been called each time an instance was newed up.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `uuid.v1()` actually returns a string, so you are setting the default to the same uuid.  Instead, pass it the function: `uuid.v1` (without parentheses).

Comment: Good catch!  The parens were leftover from a function wrapper.  Didn't even see them there after a while.  Thanks.  :)